# `kate -n new.txt %u` in Dolphin service menu saves one level up

Tags: text, dolphin, kate, servicemenu

When creating a new Dolphin service menu to create a new text file using Kate (given there is no shortcut for that like for folders and that the menu option is rather hidden under multiple clicks as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284512/925128)), using a desktop file like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Icon=kate
Actions=new-file
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin,inode/directory
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

[Desktop Action new-file]
Name=New text file
Icon=kate
Exec=kate %u
```

Kate creates the file not within the selected directory, but at the same path as that directory, one level up than expected: selecting folder `/PATH/TO/MY_DIRECTORY` and using the context menu service, the text file is ready to be saved at `/PATH/TO` instead of `/PATH/TO/MY_DIRECTORY`.

The same happens with `Exec=kate -n new.txt %u`, as the file is created *and* saved.

How to make Kate save or offer to save **within the selected directory**?

How to do it inside the selected folder?

Comment: I got a possible solution using a script, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `%u` is expanded to the current directory, you can do something like this (it works in my testing):

Create an executable script with the following content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

c=0

for f in "$1/"new*.txt; do
  if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
    ((c++)) 
  fi
done

f="$1/new-$c.txt"
touch "$f"
kate "$f"
```

Then in your `desktop` file:

```
...
Exec=/path/to/script/script %f
...
```